# Having both GROUP BY and ORDER BY in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I've been told that I can't have GROUP BY and ORDER BY in one MySQL Query.  Here is an abbreviated version of the query -

```
SELECT n.colorName, n.colorComp, n.colorID, SUM(n.gallons) AS TotalGallons
FROM netTran n, Store m, Product p
WHERE ((n.store = m.store) and m.state = "FL")
AND ((n.salesNbr = p.salesNbr) AND (p.intExt = "EXTERIOR" OR p.intExt = "INT/EXT"))
AND ((n.clrnt1 = "L1") AND (n.clrnt1 = "R3"))
GROUP BY n.colorComp, n.colorID
ORDER BY TotalGallons DESC;
```

I've been told that having the ORDER BY with the GROUP BY will give me different results and that the only way the ORDER BY would work is if the main query were nested in

```
SELECT * FROM
(query)
ORDER BY TotalGallons DESC;
```

Is that correct?

Comment: No, that is not correct. `ORDER BY` works just fine following a `GROUP BY`; it will give you the same results in a different order; the only way you will get different results is if you also have a LIMIT. in fact if you wanted some thing "the three colors with the most total gallons", you would want that first query to also have `LIMIT 3`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the query as

```
SELECT n.colorName, n.colorComp, n.colorID, SUM(n.gallons) AS     TotalGallons
FROM netTran n, Store m, Product p
WHERE ((n.store = m.store) and m.state = "FL")
AND ((n.salesNbr = p.salesNbr) AND (p.intExt = "EXTERIOR" OR p.intExt = "INT/EXT"))
AND ((n.clrnt1 = "L1") AND (n.clrnt1 = "R3"))
GROUP BY n.colorName, n.colorComp,n.colorID
ORDER BY TotalGallons DESC;
```

You can have grouo by and order by in a single query. But you need to provide all columns in case of you are aggregating a column

Comment: Order by provides you the data in ascending or descending order. Group by aggregates the column. Hope you got an idea, else will explain you clearly

Comment: That makes more sense.  Thank you.

Comment: If you are going to rewrite the query, you should (1) motivate why and (2) use proper `join` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Group by will change  the results.. Order by will just  present data in order..

Having the ORDER BY with the GROUP BY won't give you different results

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's true. In the [mysql reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) you can read th

*If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted according to the GROUP BY columns as if you had an ORDER BY for the same columns. To avoid the overhead of sorting that GROUP BY produces, add ORDER BY NULL:*

I suppose that this means that ORDER BY has no effect at all.

Curious... I always thought that order by worked...

Comment: My guess would be *that* `ORDER BY` overrides the implicit ordering of the `GROUP BY`, preventing `GROUP BY` from doing the ordering at all. However, they've warned that `GROUP BY` even doing the ordering is a deprecated behavior and not to assume it will be there in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are two different things. It is plain wrong that you cannot use them together.

`GROUP BY` is used to tell the DBMS per which group to aggregate the data. In your example you sum `gallons` *per* `colorComp` and `colorID`.

`ORDER BY` is used to tell the DBMS in which order you want the data shown. In your query by the sum of `gallons` descending.

In standard SQL you don't usually use `GROUP BY` without `ORDER BY`, because in spite of the grouping, the data may be shown unordered. MySQL however decided to guarantee that `GROUP BY` performs an `ORDER BY`. So in MySQL it was not necessary to use `ORDER BY` after `GROUP BY`, as long as you didn't want *another* order as in your example. This non-standard behavior is now deprecated. See here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html

> However, relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting is deprecated.

So you should have an `ORDER BY` clause now whenever you want data sorted. With no exception.